How come strong nucleophiles can also be weak bases?
I'm currently taking an introductory organic chemistry course, and have come across the idea that strong nucleophiles can simultaneously also be weak bases numerous times. Also that this can then help us decide if a certain nucleophile favours E2 over SN2 (or E1 over SN1).
Something about this just doesn't seem to add up. As far as I know, "bases" are just a subset of nucleophiles - they react with protons instead of electrophiles in general. If this is true, wouldn't a weaker base (i.e. a weaker ability to attract protons) automatically imply a weaker ability to attract electrophiles too?
If not, why? Further, how exactly does this distinction help us determine whether or not a reaction would proceed via elimination or substitution (in the case of a secondary alkyl halide)?

Well, in general definition you wouldn't have 'non-nucleophilic base', would you? In the context of org. chem. nucleophile strength is estimated vs carbon.

Even still, isn't it contradictory to suggest that a compound can be a good nucleophile when estimated vs carbon, but a weak base when estimated vs hydrogen?

Mmm, I knew I should say it more strongly. In org. chem. nucleophile is not what abstracts the proton. The categories are separate.
